# How to sum rows with the same date from a derived table in Mysql8.0? and why GROUP BY failed?

Tags: mysql, group-by

This is the code. The problem is the result has duplicate Date. I want to sum the amt of duplicate dates of each column by GROUP BY, but it says "this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by",

Someone suggestes to turn off this setting. I don's know how and wonder any better way to solve it.

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `Date` DATE NOT NULL,
  `USD` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `EUR` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `test` VALUES
  ('2020-03-06', -1000000,6930860),
  ('2020-03-07', -1000000,6930860),
  ('2020-04-13', -2000000,13966090),
  ('2020-05-13', -2000000,13963260),
  ('2020-05-28',  1000000,-654773.8),
  ('2020-06-01',  1000000,-1135530);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test2` (
  `Date` DATE NOT NULL,
  `USD` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `EUR` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `test2` VALUES
  ('2020-03-05', -1000011,6930860),
  ('2020-03-09', -1000022,6930860),
  ('2020-04-3', -2000033,13966090),
  ('2020-05-10', -2000044,13963260),
  ('2020-05-28',  1000055,-654773.8),
  ('2020-06-01',  1000066,-1135530);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT * FROM
  ((SELECT * FROM
      (SELECT Date FROM test
      UNION
      SELECT Date FROM test2
      ORDER BY Date) AS d
  LEFT OUTER JOIN test USING (Date))
  UNION
  (SELECT * FROM
      (SELECT Date FROM test
      UNION
      SELECT Date FROM test2
      ORDER BY Date) AS d2
  LEFT OUTER JOIN test2 USING (Date))) AS D
ORDER BY Date ASC;
```

```
| Date       | USD      | EUR       |
| ---------- | -------- | --------- |
| 2020-03-05 | -1000011 | 6930860   |
| 2020-03-05 |          |           |
| 2020-03-06 | -1000000 | 6930860   |
| 2020-03-06 |          |           |
| 2020-03-07 | -1000000 | 6930860   |
| 2020-03-07 |          |           |
| 2020-03-09 | -1000022 | 6930860   |
| 2020-03-09 |          |           |
| 2020-04-03 | -2000033 | 13966090  |
| 2020-04-03 |          |           |
| 2020-04-13 | -2000000 | 13966090  |
| 2020-04-13 |          |           |
| 2020-05-10 |          |           |
| 2020-05-10 | -2000044 | 13963260  |
| 2020-05-13 | -2000000 | 13963260  |
| 2020-05-13 |          |           |
| 2020-05-28 | 1000000  | -654773.8 |
| 2020-05-28 | 1000055  | -654773.8 |
| 2020-06-01 | 1000000  | -1135530  |
| 2020-06-01 | 1000066  | -1135530  |
```

I want the result like this.
1. One date in one row, and
2. SUM the amount on the same date.
3. delete null rows.

[image]

Thank you.

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ikovjKXwYRAE6eC74UEQ6y/3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is `UNION ALL` for the 2 tables and aggregation:

```
select t.Date, sum(t.USD) USD, sum(t.EUR) EUR
from (
  select * from test
  union all
  select * from test2
) t 
group by t.Date
order by t.Date
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gXJfEN8amsVq4r4XxpKMGo/1).
Results:

```
| Date       | USD      | EUR        |
| ---------- | -------- | ---------- |
| 2020-03-05 | -1000011 | 6930860    |
| 2020-03-06 | -1000000 | 6930860    |
| 2020-03-07 | -1000000 | 6930860    |
| 2020-03-09 | -1000022 | 6930860    |
| 2020-04-03 | -2000033 | 13966090   |
| 2020-04-13 | -2000000 | 13966090   |
| 2020-05-10 | -2000044 | 13963260   |
| 2020-05-13 | -2000000 | 13963260   |
| 2020-05-28 | 2000055  | -1309547.6 |
| 2020-06-01 | 2000066  | -2271060   |
```

Note: although MySql is very flexible when it comes to implicit data type conversions, you should not use the `VARCHAR` data type for numeric values.
Instead use for this case `DECIMAL(13,2)`

Comment: "ORDER BY t.Date" should not be followed in case of ASC sorting. It makes your query slower. Group By clause makes results sorted automatically.

Comment: @LikiCrus There is no ASC after ORDER BY t.date. Also click the link of the demo and remove the order by clause. You will see that GROUP BY does not always sort.

Comment: Thanks for your correctness! I noticed that GROUP BY doesn't sort implicitly in 8.0.

Comment: which one is better between `group by t.Date order by t.Date` and `group by t.Date ASC`?

Comment: There is no choice of better or worse. If you want the results sorted you can't rely only to `group by` because as you can see by this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eDJTurYxzzNZszxJjraSCR/15 (for MySql 8.0) and this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eDJTurYxzzNZszxJjraSCR/16 (for MySql 5.7) the behavior of `group by` when it comes to sorting is not reliable. So use ORDER BY to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following query. I hope it would work as you expected.

PS. Please don't use "ORDER BY DATE" in your subquery. This will make your query slow.

```
SELECT Date FROM test2
      ORDER BY Date
```

```
SELECT 
    `DATE`,
    SUM(USD) AS USD,
    SUM(EUR) AS EUR 
FROM
    (
        (SELECT 
            * 
        FROM
            (SELECT 
                DATE 
            FROM
                test 
            UNION
            SELECT 
                DATE 
            FROM
                test2) AS d 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN test USING (DATE)) 
        UNION
        (SELECT 
            * 
        FROM
            (SELECT 
                DATE 
            FROM
                test 
            UNION
            SELECT 
                DATE 
            FROM
                test2) AS d2 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN test2 USING (DATE))
    ) AS D 
GROUP BY `DATE` ;
```

Comment: yes.You are right. ORDER BY  Date is slow in my real database.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
WITH 
dates AS ( SELECT test.Date FROM test 
           UNION
           SELECT test2.Date FROM test2 ),
total AS ( SELECT *
           FROM dates
           LEFT JOIN test USING(Date) 
           UNION ALL
           SELECT *
           FROM dates
           LEFT JOIN test2 USING(Date) )
SELECT total.Date, SUM(USD) USD, SUM(EUR) EUR
FROM total
GROUP BY total.Date
ORDER BY total.Date;
```

or

```sql
WITH 
dates AS ( SELECT test.Date FROM test 
           UNION
           SELECT test2.Date FROM test2 ),
total AS ( SELECT *
           FROM test
           UNION ALL
           SELECT *
           FROM test2 )
SELECT dates.Date, SUM(total.USD) USD, SUM(total.EUR) EUR
FROM dates
JOIN total USING (Date)
GROUP BY dates.Date
ORDER BY dates.Date;
```

or

```sql
WITH 
total AS ( SELECT *
           FROM test
           UNION ALL
           SELECT *
           FROM test2 ),
dates AS ( SELECT DISTINCT total.Date 
           FROM total )
SELECT dates.Date, SUM(total.USD) USD, SUM(total.EUR) EUR
FROM dates
JOIN total USING (Date)
GROUP BY dates.Date
ORDER BY dates.Date;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c10e9dce46a0f0eab4fd7533d9dd7244)

And a lot of another variants...